# Parity RPC eth_newFilter not returning pending events

Tags: parity, json-rpc

I'm trying to create a listener for new pending TXs on the network using Parity RPC's `eth_newFilter` method.

I'm sending the request using the following parameters, expecting to get pending transactions back when I call `eth_getFilterChanges`. However, I only get transactions as they are mined into a block.

Shouldn't this give me pending transactions (not yet mined)? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
parameters_to_send = {
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_newFilter",
    "params":[{
        "fromBlock": "pending",
        "toBlock": "pending"
    }],
    "id":1
}
```

I know there is a method for `eth_newPendingTransactionFilter`, but the data returned using a custom `eth_newFilter` is a bit better for my purposes.

Thanks!